# Translating (Block: Objective-C ) to (Closure: Swift) Please verify my code

Tags: swift, block

I'm trying to translate ObjC code to swift version. And I have some confusing points between 'Block' and 'Closure'.

1. As Images show that, there is a "completion:^(...)" which made me have no idea to solve it.
2. And what are the meaning of "if(halfway) halfway(finished)" and "if(completion) completion(finished)"? why there are exist ";" after control flows?

A big appreciation for your help and guide.

Ethan Joe

ObjC Version:

```
- (void)flipTransitionWithOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options halfway:(void (^)(BOOL finished))halfway completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
{
    CGFloat degree = (options & UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight) ? -M_PI_2 : M_PI_2;
```

```
CGFloat duration = 0.4;
CGFloat distanceZ = 2000;
CGFloat translationZ = self.frame.size.width / 2;
CGFloat scaleXY = (distanceZ - translationZ) / distanceZ;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -distanceZ; // perspective
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 0, 0, translationZ);

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DScale(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, scaleXY, scaleXY, 1.0);
self.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration / 2 animations:^{
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, degree, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (halfway) halfway(finished);
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, -degree, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration / 2 animations:^{
        self.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        if (completion) completion(finished);
    }];
}];
```

---

My Swift Version:
    func flipTransitionWithOptions(var options:UIViewAnimationOptions, _halfway halfway:((finished: Bool) -> Void)?, _completion completion:((finished: Bool) -> Void)?) {
        var degree: CGFloat!
        if(options == UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight){
            degree = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
        } else {
            degree = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
        }
        var duration: CGFloat = 0.4
        var distanceZ: CGFloat = 2000
        var translationZ: CGFloat = self.frame.width / 2
        var scaleXY: CGFloat = (distanceZ - translationZ) / distanceZ

var rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
    rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform.m34 = 1.0 / (-distanceZ)
    rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform = CATransform3DTranslate(rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform, 0, 0, translationZ)
    rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform = CATransform3DScale(rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform, scaleXY, scaleXY, 1.0)
    layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform, degree, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)}, completion: {finished in
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform, -degree, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform}, completion: {finished in self.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity})
    })

}

Comment: Next time, instead of posting images of code, if there are just a few lines it's better to copy the relevant code using the formatting tool Code Snippet.

Comment: OK, I am new to Stack, and I will check that how to use "Code Snippet".

Comment: @EthanJoe if you indent a line 4 spaces it gets put into a grey code block area and syntax formatted, or if you enclose quotes in back-tics . in a comment or text it looks like `this` Or use the code formatting block icon in the question/answer editor "{}"  Also be sure to up-vote any answer that is useful by clicking the up-arrow (also up-vote questions on StackOverflow you find useful), and if you find  a good answer to a question you post,  click the check mark next to the answer that actually solves your problem. It doesn't mean it's the best answer, just that it solved the asker's problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the parameter name `finished` with `_` in any situation where you are are not using the `finished` parameter. In the Objective C version, `finished` was being passed to an additional function handler that you omitted from the Swift translation.

`_` in swift means the parameter is unused.  In the Swift documentation, it shows you that many items from closures can be omitted if unused, so be sure to study the Swift language guide for those nuances and options.

^{ } format is ObjC only, not needed in Swift.  Just the { }

It looks like the developer added lines to optionally call *supplemental* completion handler functions (if they exist) ... called `halfway` and `completion`, respectively.  They are almost certainly function pointers, but  `completion` is not perhaps the best choice, because it happens to be same name as the function parameter.

You should check the original code to see if there are functions or closures named `halfway` or `completion` in their source code to be sure you didn't leave out some essential code that also needs to be called when the completion runs.

Comment: Thank you at the first place. In order to show the whole code, can you teach me how to write the code in the Comment while using formatting tool Code Snippet.

Comment: @EthanJoe I explained that in a comment I added below your original question.

Comment: If anyone helped you, please up-vote their answers. If you used a solution, please click the checkmark to accept it. People work hard to jump in and help people, so give something back please.

Comment: Sorry about that. They said vote up needs at least 15 reputations, but I just have 12 reputation.